# Free solution for reading/creating/updating excel files from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Has to be free.
Has to support all versions of Excel files.
Has to have C# .NET API.

I need to do all of the specified actions (reading/creating/updating).

Has anyone used any library l this kind sucessfully

Update:

I read a lot of bad things about Ole DB, and Interop is not an option since this is a web application running on a server.

Comment: I have used this for creating, updating: http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/ I'm not sure if it supports all versions of Excel. It certainly supports 2003 and 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use OleDB [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

Comment: Open XML supports .xls files?

Comment: I think it doesn't. Try to use OleDB: look at the link in my post.

Answer (score 1):

From a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416722/better-option-for-hosting-ms-office-documents-in-custom-app/3458960#3458960) on a different question:

- You might consider using the Excel object model and COM interop to read the data from the Excel file into your application.  Granted, this includes a dependency on Excel being installed, but it is a possibility.  [This article](http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop) has some great code for getting started with reading Excel files in this way.
- A better way might be to use a library that doesn't have a dependency on Excel being installed on the local system.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449541/exporting-excel-to-c/3449613#3449613) suggests using the [Excel Data Reader library](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/), available on CodePlex.

Like I pointed out in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416722/better-option-for-hosting-ms-office-documents-in-custom-app/3458960#3458960), there are paid third-party libraries that will likely do *exactly* what you are looking for.  I understand you want something that is free, but in my experience with free Excel libraries, you tend to need to do a good bit of extra work to get it to play the right way.

Comment: Excel Data Reader Library looks great but it says there that it has not yet added support for Excel 2007 Binary files.

Comment: Excel Data Reader now supports .xlsx (2007) files

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx). It does all you want but it isn't free. I don't know any other products that can fit all your needs (All Excel Versions, C# Api, Read/Write, etc)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a good option but I'm not sure my employer would be willing to pay that money.